# Is it possible to add new aggregated column for TimescaleDB continuous aggregate view?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I've already have TimescaleDB continuous aggregate view. I want add one column with aggregated minimum values. I don't want recreate, because the view has older data than basic. Does TimescaleDB support this action?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot alter columns in continuous aggregates (yet). You need to drop it and recreate it with the proper columns.

Edit: In case you have data in the cont. agg based on older data that's not available anymore in the hypertable, you have two options:

OPTION 1:
Insert the materialized data back into the hypertable. Then create the new cont. agg. with the new column(s) + need to disable the data retention policy until the new CAgg is done refreshing the older data.
(**Important**: with this solution, if you run sth like AVG() the data that comes back might not be totally accurate)

OPTION 2:
UNION the old cont. agg. when querying the new one (in this case you wouldn't have the new column(s) for older data)

Comment: The issue is, view has older data than basic table. If I drop the view, I can't recreate the oldest data (all about retention policy).

Comment: check my edit @grzesiu988